# Where to install programs in Arch Linux?

Tags: installation, filesystems, file-management, arch-linux

I am virtually new to the Linux scene altogether. I recently downloaded Matlab for installation. I unpacked the files and ran `./install` to start the wizard. As I was stepping through it asked me for an install path with a default of `/usr/local/Matlab`. That first off did not seem right and looked even more incorrect when I looked in that directory.

`/usr/local/` has `bin etc games include lib man sbin share src`

That being said, it's doubtful this would be the most efficient place to install a program. Where are most programs installed? I've read that it largely depends on the Linux flavor for the most part.

Any recommendations from experienced Linux users?

Comment: You can install an application in any folder you want.

Comment: Of course, but in terms of the hierarchy of a linux system where would it make most sense? I did not think having a `Matlab` directory among library bin directories made much sense.

Comment: /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin as its a user-installed application

Comment: It now asks for a path to place the symbolic links to Matlab scripts. Any suggestions? I installed Matlab in `/usr/local/bin/Matlab`

Comment: There are conventions,but within those conventions where you put things is up to you. I personally put proprietary software in `/opt`. You can likely put the symlinks anywhere in your PATH.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are a few places for apps to be installed in Arch Linux:

- for apps that follow the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard and are installed by system package manager (in case of Arch `pacman`), `/usr/` tree is used. Most commonly used parts by applications are:

  - `/usr/bin/` - this is where the app's binaries (executables) go
  - `/usr/share/` - this is where the app's other resources go (usually of the immutable kind)
- for apps that follow FHS principles, but are installed per hand (commonly compiled via `make` and installed via `make install`), `/usr/local/` is the right place. The hierarchy here mimics the one from `/usr/` and its intention is to separate manually installed stuff from the automatic, repository stuff. Please note that if you intend to keep the local packages up-to-date and install a lot of them, using [AUR](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_User_Repository), [an AUR helper](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR_helpers#Active) and learning [how to maintain packages](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PKGBUILD) is probably a better way than overcrowding `/usr/local/`.
- for apps that have more monolithic folder structure (e.g. Matlab), `/opt/` is the way to go. One usually just puts the folders there, e.g. `/opt/MonolithicApp/`, `/opt/Matlab/`, etc.
- since games tend to have the monolithic folder structure quite often, `/usr/local/games/` is a designated place to put these, aside from `/opt/`. Which one should be used is left to user's discretion.

In order to keep things convenient, some additions to `$PATH` are necessary in case of programs installed in `/opt/`. If there is a single binary, I tend to just create a symlink in `/usr/local/bin/`.

If there are more than one/two binaries, it mandates a `PATH="$PATH:/opt/MonolithicApp/bin/"` addition somewhere in the shell config files.

Sources:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/arch_filesystem_hierarchy
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

Comment: I am circling back after a few years of Linux use. I tend to follow this convention and it works pretty well. I, too, have tended to use symlinks for invoking user-installed binaries. However, some binaries assume they are being invoked from their root directories. To solve this, I have been using a simple script placed in the app's root directory (e.g. `/usr/Matlab/matlab-start.sh`) that uses `dirname` and `realpath` to `cd` to the app's root directory before passing `$@` to the target executable. What is the convention for binaries in `/usr/bin` that also have a location requirement?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of binaries you mean - files in `/usr/bin` should be put there only by your package managers (e.g. pacman, AUR helper) and a correctly built package doesn't have a 'location requirement', as you put it. Perhaps an example to illustrate your case could be helpful?

Comment: To create a new folder in `/opt` we need a `su` rights. Is it ok to place custom monolitic apps here? I assume we will be able to run it only with `sudo` then?